# FOREX position in Interactive Brokers

Tags: foreign-exchange

I've deposited money in EUR and my base currency is SEK. 
I exchanged all of those Euros into SEK and since then I have a position of 
EUR.SEK that is that deposited amount negative. As the exchange rate goes up and down so does my P/L.

I think this is weird, I'm a missing something? I have no intention to exchange those SEK back into EUR. I'll do some trading but eventually transfer it all out as SEK.

Can I get rid of that position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can get rid of the position. I can't quite remember where, possibly in the accounts section in TWS, but you can edit positions to change outstanding notional and initial price.

It obviously doesn't affect your portfolio value, but I agree it can be a bit annoying if you rely on the daily PnL figure for some information about price movements and vol of your portfolio.

Edit by OP:
There are two types of *destination*; IDEALPRO and FXCONV. 
When using webtrader IDEALPRO is the only option and when using TWS it's possible to choose.

Exchanges made with IDEALPRO always creates a Virtual FX what was what I where seeing.

Using TWS it's possible to change the amount (and value) of those virtual FX and if the value is changed to 0 it disappears.

Also, in Webtrader they does't show as virtual but as positions which is confusing. In TWS they are shown separately.

Comment: Editing the positions in TWS is possible via: Account → Account Window → FX Portfolio → Right click on forex position → Adjust Position or Average Price.

Answer (score 0):

In TWS you can do it by switching to Classic TWS and using Trading Tool -> Rebalance Portfolio.

You can specify Target% 0 for all positions you don't need and system will create orders for you.

[image: Rebalance Portfilio Tool]